# How to change a WPF Ribbon's Control ToolTipTitle font in XAML or at run-time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a RibbonButton and given its Tooltip this way

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton Label="My Label" 
     ToolTipTitle="{Binding Path=Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Now at runtime when I change my button label font family to Hindi and set label text in Hindi also, label gets displayed correctly both text wise and font wise, but tooltiptitle text matter changes (due to RelativeResource) but its font does not change (because I see text as junk characters). Which means tooltip text is changing but font is not changing.

How to change that ToolTipTitle font at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with the standard tooltip properties on the ribbon button.
But you could build your own tooltip:

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton.ToolTip>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Header" />
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="Content .... " />
  </StackPanel>
</ribbon:RibbonButton.ToolTip>
```